# How do you programmatically change the color of output to the IntelliJ console

Tags: java, intellij-14

I have a situation where I have a lot of text going to the IntelliJ console and I'd like to highlight some of the output using colors and bold etc.

Is there something I can add to my System.out.print() to make the text a particular color.

Comment: See duplicate question - The Grep Console plugin works!